# BadTokenException in ViewRootImpl

Tags: android, crash

I often get crash

Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException
Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@278263e9 is not valid; is your activity running?

from fabric.io with this or similar stacktrace:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:566)
android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView (WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView (WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3121)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2447)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:156)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1351)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:211)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5373)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1020)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:815)
de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main (XposedBridge.java:102)
```

That stacktrace isn't initialized from my code and i can't reproduce that. 
I have several variations of that stacktrace but all come to an end in method setView ViewRootImpl.java class.

I don't understand how i can find source of crash. Help me please

EDIT: code where i using fabric.io:

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(!BuildConfig.REPORT_CRASHES).build()).build());
}
```

Comment: Show us your code where you are using fabric.io

Comment: i added code where i used fabric.io

Comment: Do you know the Activity in which the crash occurs?

Comment: Sadly no. I have 3 activity but actively used only one. That activity has many code, if you say which part of code you need i give it for you

Comment: Are you showing an `AlertDialog` in any of there activities?

Comment: Yes. But i call dismiss all of them in onDestroy method

Comment: I just got this strack trace for the first time, so not very common for me (few thousand users). Very strange that it asks if activity is running when obviously it's resuming the activity. @KNeerajLal what made you think that `AlertDialog` may be cause? True, the other So questions with this error show Dialog in the stack, but not this one. Plus, if you look in ActivityThread code it's not doing anything Dialog, it's just trying to add this activity's window to the screen, AFAICT.